# My PHP Session logs in the world

Tags: php, session, authentication

I've encountered a weird problem with PHP Sessions that I'm not sure how to fix. I know that there's a problem with my code, but Googling the matter and searching for answers her yielded no results...possibly because I have no idea how to make keywords for this!

Basically I'm making a login script to learn PHP better, and so I encountered sessions. I got them working somewhat, but trouble is that when I successfully log in, the session that's created logs the world into my account no matter from where or with what browser is used.

I'm pretty sure I'm missing a step, so if anyone could help me figure that out, that'd be great!

Presently I have this on top of every page dealing with sessions:

```
session_id("tenaarFeiriSess"); // Define the session name.
@session_start();

error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

The actual login applies the session like this, where $usr = username:

```
$_SESSION['loggedin'] = $usr;
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that you give everyone the exact same session with `session_id()`.  PHP automatically sets a session id for everyone so this is really unnecessary.  Once you remove this, it should work.

Comment: Thanks! That at least took care of the global logins (I commented out session_id() ). The session doesn't stick however & is cleared right away despite getting a successful login message. Setting as accepted answer though since it did solve my initial question!

Comment: You're welcome.  A session clears by default if the user closes the page.

Comment: Got it! And now it works like it's supposed to! Just leaving a comment in case someone else stumbles over this: I had my doctype placed wrong & somehow it messed with session_start(). Removing it & putting it back where it's supposed to be issue of sessions not sticking (or starting properly as I suspect was the case)!